# How do I build dynamic functions with javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic

I'm getting myself confused with all these languages! :)

```
// given this function
var f = function(a,b) { return a == b; }

// and these values for a
var a = [1,2,3]

// how do I make this array (a is replaced by its value)?
var results = [
   function(b) { return 1 == b; },
   function(b) { return 2 == b; },
   function(b) { return 3 == b; }
]
```

Comment: how would you invoke this function?

Comment: @qwertymk I don't want to mess with its context if that's what you're getting at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function build(a) {
    return function(b) { return a == b; }
}

var results = [];
var a = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    results.push(build(a[i]));
}
```

Some output:

```
> results[0](1)
true
> results[0](2)
false
> results[1](1)
false
> results[1](2)
true
```